# How to JOIN a third table to the query and only get the newst record from that (by date)

Tags: mysql

So I have a PHP script that pulls data from two tables at the moment... How could I pull data from a third one, but only get the newest record from that third?

This is my query now:

```
  SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, r.reminder, r.cid, a.timestamp, a.practitioner FROM `records` AS r
  LEFT JOIN `clients` AS c ON (
    r.cid = c.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN `appointments` AS a ON (
    r.calid = a.id
  );
```

So what this does right now is get the r.cid (client id) and r.reminder from 'records', then use that r.cid to get the c.firstname, c.lastname from 'clients' and then finally get a.timestamp, a.practitioner from 'appointments'... What I need to do is add a 3rd table to this query, named 'logs' and pull only the newest entry (timestamp column - and actually just pull only this column coz I'm only interested in the date) for each user (cid).

So third table only has cid (same as in other table - user id), timestamp and message. I only need to pull the latest timestamp from this table for each user.

Comment: Join with that table and use `MAX(timestamp)` with appropriate grouping.

Comment: I did try and this is as far as I could get... You think I'd rather wait for answers or comments like this here instead of trying to fix myself?

Comment: @ChinaWhite You didn't post your code.  So we can only assume that you don't even bother to try do this yourself.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did try, unsuccessfully - mysql is still something fairly new to me so I saw no point in adding my gibberish code as well... I needed to do this from the get-go, I've learned how to do the join for tables, I just wasn't able to also learn how to do the last part by myself - hence I've only posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a subquery that gets the maximum log timestamp for each user.

```
  SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, r.reminder, r.cid, a.timestamp, a.practitioner, l.log_timestamp 
  FROM `records` AS r
  LEFT JOIN `clients` AS c ON (
    r.cid = c.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN `appointments` AS a ON (
    r.calid = a.id
  )
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cid, MAX(timestamp) AS log_timestamp
    FROM logs
    GROUP BY cid) AS l ON l.cid = r.cid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it - that was what I needed.